# Left-justified text forced to the right

Tags: spacing

I am creating a letterhead or other heading to be used at the top of invoices and the like and am having an issue with the spacing of one element:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Large \bfseries My Name
\end{center}

\hrulefill

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
My street \\
And my city, zip
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
(my) phone-number \\
my@email.com
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5in}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{To:}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1em}{}
    The Person \\
    His street \\
    His city, zip
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \textbf{Date:}

  \hspace*{1em}\today
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: First attempt]

I would like the "Date" block to be aligned to the right of the page similarly to the phone and email block above it. My first stab at a solution was to add `\raggedleft` and some spacing adjustment to the last `minipage`:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \raggedleft
  \textbf{Date:}\phantom{\today}\hspace*{-1.4em}

  \hspace*{1em}\today
\end{minipage}
```

[image: Second attempt--almost there!]

This *almost* works: unfortunately, I can't devise a way to make sure the horizontal distance between the start of "Date:" and the start of "January..." is exactly 1em, as I was able to specify in the "To" block.

The idea I have in my head for the solution involves something like this:

```
\hfill % or \hspace{\fill}: which is preferred here?
\begin{minipage}[t]{\the-exact-width-of-the-date-block}
  Date:

  \hspace*{1em}\today
\end{minipage}
```

But, I can't come up with a way to have TeX calculate that width for me--perhaps some sort of multi-line box that can be forced to the left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd set the blocks in separate `tabular`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Large \bfseries My Name
\end{center}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
  My street \\
  And my city, zip
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{r@{}}
  (my) phone-number \\
  my@email.com
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.5in}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\hspace{1em}}l}
  \hspace{-1em}\textbf{To:} \\
      The Person \\
      His street \\
      His city, zip
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\hspace{1em}}l@{}}
  \hspace{-1em}\textbf{Date:} \\
  \today
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, I see that my HTML experience is bleeding through--I never would have thought to use tables for *(gasp)* layout! Accepted.

Comment: @Scott: I've made a small correction in terms of the right-hand block `tabular` spacing. See the [edit revision](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/224327/revisions)...

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `varwidth` from the same package instead of `minipage`. The `varwidth` environment is similar to `minipage`, but its width is determined by its contents.

So you can simply load the package `varwidth`, substitute `minipage` with `varwidth` and add `\hfill` between consecutive `varwidth`s.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{changepage,varwidth}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \Large \bfseries My Name
\end{center}

\hrulefill

\begin{varwidth}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
My street \\
And my city, zip
\end{varwidth}\hfill
\begin{varwidth}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\raggedleft
(my) phone-number \\
my@email.com
\end{varwidth}

\vspace{0.5in}

\begin{varwidth}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\textbf{To:}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{1em}{}
    The Person \\
    His street \\
    His city, zip
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{varwidth}\hfill
\begin{varwidth}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \textbf{Date:}

  \hspace*{1em}\today
\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]